# How to plot a 3D patch collection in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I'm trying to make a 3D plot in matplotlib with three circles on it, each centered at the origin and with a radius of 1, pointing in different directions - to illustrate a sphere of radius 1, for example.

In 2D I would make a circle patch collection and add it to the axes. In 3D I'm having trouble getting the patches to show up at all, let alone orient them in different directions.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as P
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as M3

fig = P.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
circles = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(
    [matplotlib.patches.Circle((0, 0), 1) for count in range(3)],
    offsets=(0, 0))
M3.art3d.patch_collection_2d_to_3d(circles, zs=[0], zdir='z')
ax.add_collection(circles)
P.show()
```

Running this program fills the entire plot window with blue, i.e. the face color of the patches, no matter how I rotate the plot. If I set `facecolor='none'` in the `PatchCollection()` call, then an empty `Axes3D` shows up.

Things I've tried:

- If I use a `CircleCollection` instead of a `PatchCollection`, no patches show up at all.
- The `zs` parameter in the `patch_collection_2d_to_3d()` call is odd; I would expect to put either `zs=0` (one z-coordinate for all three patches) or `zs=[0,0,0]` (a separate z-coordinate for each patch), but both of those throw an error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

To orient the patches differently, I would expect to be able to pass something like `zdir=['x', 'y', 'z']` but the results are no different whether I pass that or `'z'` or `['z']`.

I would also have expected to be able to do `ax.add_collection3d(circles, zs=[0, 0, 0], zdir=['x', 'y', 'z'])` instead of converting the patch collection from 2d to 3d, but that throws an error too:

> AttributeError: 'Patch3DCollection' object has no attribute 'set_sort_zpos'

Comment: @Lilith's answer is an excellent alternate approach; can anybody enlighten me as to why my approach didn't work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, PathPatch
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d


fig = plt.figure()
ax=fig.gca(projection='3d')

for i in ["x","y","z"]:
    circle = Circle((0, 0), 1)
    ax.add_patch(circle)
    art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(circle, z=0, zdir=i)


ax.set_xlim3d(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim3d(-2, 2)
ax.set_zlim3d(-2, 2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: how can one generalize this to center the circle at (x,y,z) = (a,b,c)?