# Matplotlib Axes3d, line intersect with 2d object

Tags: python, matplotlib, intersection

I am trying to do [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/bbox_intersect.html) but in 3d and using a 2d circle instead of a box.

I have a line starting between the two points `[ (0,0,0), (3,4,5) ]` and I want to see if it intersects through

`circle = Circle((2, 1), 0.5)`

`ax.add_patch(circle)`

`art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(circle, z=1, zdir="x")`

Is it possible to test for a path intersect on a 2d object plotted on 3d axis? From the linked example above, I want to do `path.intersects_circle` where I define a circle as:

I have had a look through the `Bbox` documentation and it seems that I can't use this method for a circle?

Comment: How do you define the intersection of objects defined in different dimensions? Are you looking for an intersection of the projection? I'm afraid your question is not well posed.

Comment: In the example I linked, from my understanding, if a line passed through the `Bbox` then this changes the colour of the line.  I'm looking to change the colour of the line, and also keep a log of the number of lines that pass through the circle.  I don't specifically need to know the x,y,z of where it passed through the circle.  Hope that makes a bit more sense?

Comment: That is downstream of the problem I describe. Conceptually, I don't understand what it means when a 2d object intersects a 3d object. That doesn't make any sense to me, since both objects are defined in different spaces.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to post an image of the graph I have, but I can't post as I don't have enough posts to allow me to do this. If you were to plot just one the circles <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304116/how-to-plot-a-3d-patch-collection-in-matplotlib">here</a>, that is what I am calling my 2d object.  Changed wording in question to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you are looking for the intersection of a 2d object (the circle) with the *projection* of a 3d object. I don't think there is anything built into mpl to achieve that. After all, mpl is more focused on 2d plotting.

Comment: Ok, looks like I will have to manually try and do this.  Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like an algebraic problem than related to `matplotlib`.
This is how I understand your question:

- you have a circle at (`x=2`,`y=1`) with a radius of `r=0.5`
- this circle is located in a plane at a constant `z=1`

1.) You need to determine where your vector pierces the plane which is parallel to the `x,y`-plane and at `z=1`. For the vector you specify in your question this intersection is at:

```
x = 3./(2.**0.5)
y = 4./(2.**0.5)
z = 1.
```

2.) You need to determine if this intersection falls into the part of the plane covered by the circle. The maximum `y-coordinate` your circle reaches is `1.5` - the `y-coordinate` of the intersection is already larger. Hence your straight line does not pierce the circle.

All this being said, I would recommend implementing an algebraic check based on the intersection with the plane and determining if this intersection is part of the circle. And only then using `matplotlib`.